# Problems with Google Contacts Example "Select specific contact data"

Tags: java, android-intent, contacts

I am using the example from google https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html 
works fine to launch the contacts browser using following code.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, PHONE_ACTIVITY);
    }
```

I select a contact and the activity exits and calls my onActivityResult()

However when I use the example code to get the result from the Intent it throws and illegal column exception data1 when it gets to the last line for the query()

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case (PHONE_ACTIVITY): {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactUri = data.getData();
                String[] projection = new String[]{CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection,
                        null, null, null);
             }}}}
```

I have no clue what is wrong. Data is in the Uri but I get the following stack dump.

```
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/2942i5ae4d5758914f9df.3247i232/225 flg=0x1 }} to activity {}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3322)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3365)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1315)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:374)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:370)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at 
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5242)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3318)
11-04 19:24:01.711: E/AndroidRuntime(5790):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, bottom line if someone was interested was that the google example has a bug. The general approach is right and you call contacts with the code, but this again breaks down to the Contacts interface being a little complicated and poorly documented. I set the projection to null and parsed the data out like this.

```
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri,
                    null, null, null, null);
            // If the cursor returned is valid, get the phone number
            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                int numberIndex = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer
                        .parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver
                            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                    new String[] { contact_id }, null);
                    boolean found = false;
                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNumber = phoneCursor
                                .getString(phoneCursor
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        int phoneType = phoneCursor.getInt(phoneCursor
                                .getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                        if (phoneType == Phone.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll(
                                    "[^\\d]", "");
                            if (phoneNumber.startsWith("1")) {
                                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substring(1,
                                        phoneNumber.length());
                            }}}}
```